# importing excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

Actually i have done one sample project using node.js and mongoDB which allows users to save comments and now i am doing exporting and importing

On click of export button it will download a excel file with username and comment fields
and user have to write username and comment in downloaded excel file and now on click of import button it will display a dialog box  an it will show a button choose file..here we need to select and upload the excel

on successful upload the data will be stored in mongoDB database.

i have done exporting excel using javascript,npm libraries and now i want to  import the excel data and store it in mongoDB.

can any one pls help mee how to import excel and store data in mongodb....

Answer (score 0):

I've done import with `.csv` using [`ya-csv`](https://github.com/koles/ya-csv).

[`node-csv`](http://www.adaltas.com/projects/node-csv/) is another popular project but its API is too difficult for me to cope with.

PS: I'm interested in how you export your data to Excel, is it in `.xls` or `.csv`?

Comment: it is in .xls i used npm lib----export excel

Comment: Thx. Then using xlsx as tag on npm I came up with [this](https://npmjs.org/package/excel-parser).